# In/within/inside the box

Tags: differences

My question is quite simple.

The item should be packed very tight so it doesn't move in/within/inside the box? Which ones are correct to use? When could I use the others?

Thank you very much!:)

Comment: _Move about inside the box_ would probably be the most idiomatic.

Comment: All are fine to use. "move in the box" is very common (Google shows it's used in lots of sites giving packing advice) and maybe you want to use the shortest, although you might want to emphasise the "inside" aspect more and use another word for that.

Comment: Thank you! I think I will use move about inside the box to make sure I am very specific about it.